# Сайт атакует GoogleBots

Tags: php, linux, apache2, взлом

Недавно на сайте заметил проблемы с сессиями. Оказалось закончились INODE'ы. Потом очистил папку с сессиями и начал писать сессии в БД. И узнал что сайт атакует GoogleBots. Покопавшись, узнал что сайт мой взломали. Это были японские SEO атаки. Сделал все необходимое, посмотрел безопасность сервера, права файлов менял, проверял и вручную и через антивирусы сайт на вредоносный код. Ничего не нашел, потом домен перевел на обычный хостинг и руте сайте поставил только один файл (index.php):

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query_string = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$str = "$time\t$ip_address\t$query_string\t$user_agent\r\n";

file_put_contents('log.txt', $str, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Получается другой сервер, кода совсем нет, но все равно атакует боты Гугла, и не только гугла, там есть и яндекс боты, и бинга и т.д.д.
Там боты атакуют не каждую секунду, а в непрерывно.

[image: Это записи сессии, log файл точно такой же]

Конечно можно блокировать эти IP, но это не выход.
Кто сталкивался? В чем проблема? Я не думаю, что проблема в коде или в настройке сервера или в БД.

Comment: А с чего вывод что это бот? А если так, что мешает добавить запрет на индексацию сайта через robots.txt, либо [мета-заголовка](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=ru)?

Comment: Ничего не мешает умник, я это пробывал. Я пробывал и перепробовал все методы. Ты внимательно читал? Если это не твой уровень ответа, то не парь мозг

Comment: Вообще-то умник здесь вы, если думаете что другие будут читать вышли мысли и предугадывать что вы там сделали и написали об этом в виде «сделал всё необходимое», а после этого ещё и ожидающий что после таких комментариев вам решат помочь с решением. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Да тут много проблем может быть:

- Полное не понимание как это работает (боты ходят постоянно и в это не должно быть проблемой)
- Долгое хранение сессий
- Кривые настройки php (храните разумное время сессии например в redis)
- В robots.txt ботам можно указать [Crawl-delay](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html)
- Возможно не держит нагрузку говнохостинг (можно спрятаться за какой-то CDN)
- Возможно что-то стоит запретить индексировать в robots.txt
- Было бы не плохо сделать [sitemaps](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) что бы боты не обходили сайт почем зря